# Simple stored proc with simple cursor won't compile

Tags: mysql, database-cursor

I have been researching for hours how to create a simple MySQL cursor inside a stored proc (from Workbench), but no matter what I try, I always get this error:

> Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Here is my stored proc:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ApplyNewFormFieldsToExistingPolicies;
CREATE PROCEDURE ApplyNewFormFieldsToExistingPolicies(argAgencyID int)
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE t AS INT; -- TruckerID
  DECLARE a AS INT; -- AgentID
  DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR FOR SELECT AgentUserID AS AgentID, ID AS TruckerID from Users where IsTrucker = 1 AND AgencyID = argAgencyID
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  OPEN cursor1;

  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cursor1 INTO t, a;

    -- do something with 't'
    -- do something with 'a'

  END LOOP;
  CLOSE cursor1;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

This sql is valid and returns expected data:

```
SELECT AgentUserID AS AgentID, ID AS TruckerID from Users where IsTrucker = 1 AND AgencyID = 1
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The `;` at the end of the `DROP ...` should be `//`

Comment: Nick: I made that change and I still get the error.

Comment: So are you getting the error when you enter the code or when you call the procedure?

Comment: Error occurs during attempted creation - not getting far enough to run it. When you copy/paste my proc into your Workbench, and try to create it, what happens?

Comment: There's a few typos - you shouldn't have `AS` in your `DECLARE` statements, and you are missing a `;` at the end of the `DECLARE cursor1` statement

Comment: Thanks Nick, that was it.

Comment: Great. Glad you got it working.